# VS 2012 could not start debugger error

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I hope some one can help me it is bothering me this issue for 2 days for now. When I try to debug an app I allays receive the following message:

Unable to start debugger error code(0x80040154), It this problem persists may be a faulted instalation. Please go to control panel add remove programs and reapir instalation.

This happened after installing the VS 2012 Update 2.
So I uninstalled the update 2 but the issue remained.
I did a VS repair, the Issue remain.
I did re install of the VS (uninstall-> re install from scratch) + the update 1 but after this, the VS could not start simply (VS stopped responding...checking solution on line...closing the app).

So I do not do a complete format of the PC because I have a lot  of stuff in it.

If any one can suggest a way to resolve the issue I will be very grateful.

UPDATE:

Uninstall the update 2 of the VS 2012 and then start the repair tool, then install the Update 1, start the VS in safe mode, uninstall the extensions, and re install the exensions...it works...but do not install the update 2

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problem. I cannot start debugger after installation update 2 for Visual Studio 2012.
I cannot find any dependency on other things. This ocuring only on my PC, another comupers in my office are OK although they have same HW and SW (OS and other programs installed from same deployment image).

Comment: this happened to me after the Update 2 of the VS 2012, but the solution that was working for me was...simply uninstall update 2,  do a VS repair and then again install the update 1, and skip the update 2..with it there is an issue....it simply does not work on my pc too although the other guys have the same pc, same os, same programs intaled too as in your case.

Answer (score 0):

This error is firing because of an administrator rights issue. 
Please right click the shortcut of Visual Studio 2012 and click "Run as Administrator".

If you want to permanently enable "Run as Administrator" option:

1. Right click shortcut and select properties
2. Click Advanced
3. Check "Always run as administrator" option and click OK to close dialog box.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the issue was not that because I always run VS as administrator. The issue was reported by many others so the complete uninstall with removing items from registry, and reinstall with update 3 solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

go to registration and delete microsoftvisualstudio registration file
Removed the  registry entries.

Note that I did not delete or clean up HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0 which contained the license key

best regards